# How to split a word using java regex?

Tags: java, regex

I am using JSOUP package for getting a specific TITLE search like facebook title's . Here is my code which gives the output with TITLE's. From the TITLE's I want to select facebook URL.

PROGRAM :

```js
package googlesearch;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class SearchRegexDiv {
  private static String REGEX = ".?[facebook]";
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
    String google = "http://www.google.com/search?q=";
    //String search = "stackoverflow";
    String search = "hortonworks";
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    String userAgent = "ExampleBot 1.0 (+http://example.com/bot)"; // Change this to your company's name and bot homepage!

    Elements links = Jsoup.connect(google + URLEncoder.encode(search, charset)).userAgent(userAgent).get().select(".g>.r>a");

    for (Element link: links) {
      String title = link.text();
      String url = link.absUrl("href"); // Google returns URLs in format "http://www.google.com/url?q=<url>&sa=U&ei=<someKey>".
      url = URLDecoder.decode(url.substring(url.indexOf('=') + 1, url.indexOf('&')), "UTF-8");

      if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
        continue; // Ads/news/etc.
      }

      //.?facebook
      if (title.matches(REGEX)) {
        System.out.println("Done");
        title.substring(title.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1); //split the String  
        //(example.substring(example.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1));
      }
      System.out.println("Title: " + title);

      System.out.println("URL: " + url);
    }
  }
}
```

OUTPUT :

`Title: Hortonworks - Facebook logo
 URL: https://www.facebook.com/hortonworks/`

From the output I get the list of `URL's` and `TITLE's` in the above format.

I am trying to match Title containing word Facebook and I want to split it into two strings like

```
String socila_media = facebook;

String org = hortonworks;
```

Comment: JAVA is not JavaScript, Removed tag

Comment: May be i missing something, but how is this related to perl? Removed perl tag.

Comment: Perhaps perl regex gurus would be useful :)

Comment: Well ... you have described what you want to do. Unfortunately, you forgot to tell us what problems you have.

Comment: I know that @mplungjan its asking to post those so I have done that tag

Comment: It was suggesting based on you typing in JAVA and REGEX

Comment: I have said no @Seelenvirtuose okay, My problem is in the output you can see the title no, In that TITLE I want Facebook to one stirng and Hortonworks to other string which I have mentioned that in the last as          String socila media = facebook

String org = hortonworks

Comment: @mplungjan & bunny sunny : there's a `PCRE` tag for that (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions). However, the `regex` tag should be enough, PCRE being the most widely used regex flavour.

Answer (score 0):

use this code to split you `String` using multiple Character

Here is a [Demo To Split character using multiple param](https://ideone.com/01TX2D)

```
  String word = "https://www.facebook.com/hortonworks/";
       String [] array = word.split("[/.]");
      for (String each1 : array)
      System.out.println(each1);
```

Output is

```
https:   //each splitted word in different line.
www
facebook
com
hortonworks
```

Comment: Thank you @Kashyap it helped me